# Delphi XE and ServerMethods

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, datasnap

With Delphi XE I create a client-server application with "DataSnap Server" Wizard.

In the `ServerMethodUnit` I Define a `TSQLQuery` with sql property like this "Select * from TABLE"

I define a function called `ChangeSQL` in `ServerMethodUnit` too, what change the sql property by example `SELECT * from TABLE where ID = 5`

When i Call `ChangeSQL` form Client Application through `TSQLServerMethod`, the `ChangeSQL` function 
 change `SQL` property in the `ServerMethodUnit`, but when it leaves the function `ChangeSQL`, the `TSQLQuery` not containing the new sql command but has the original sql.

EDIT: Addition of code sample

I create a new a client-server application with "DataSnap Server" Wizard.

In `ServerMethodsUnit`:

I put a `TSQLConnection` to my database.
I Put a `TSQLQuery` call `MyQuery`, with `SQL` property = 'Select * from client'
I put a `TDataSetProvider` to `TSQLQuery`

And define a function like this:

```
function TServerMethods1.ClientFiltrer (ID:integer):integer;
begin
```

// ------------------------------------------------ 
   // At this point, MyQuery.RecordCount = all records (both the first time and the following)
   // ------------------------------------------------

```
if MyQuery.Active then
   MyQuery.close;

MyQuery.SQL.Clear;
MyQuery.SQL.Add(' SELECT * from CLIENT where ID = '+StrToInt (ID));
MyQuery.Open;
result := MyQuery.RecordCount; 
// ------------------------------------------------ 
// At this point, MyQuery.RecordCount = ONE record
// ------------------------------------------------ 

end;
```

AND THEN
I create a new application with "DataSnap CLient"

In the `ClientModuleUni`:
I put a `ClientDataSet`, called `MyClientDS` with `RemoteServer` and `ProviderName` to my `MyQuery` provider.
I put a `TSQLServerMethod` called `MyMethod` pointing to `ClientFilter` in `ServerMethodsUnit`

In a form of the client application
Then I put A `DataSource` and a `DBGrid` to `MyClientDs` and open it.
I put a `Tbutton` with code `OnClick`:

```
begin
  MyClientDs .Close;
  MyMethod .ParamByName('ID').Value := 5;
  MyMethod .ExecuteMethod;
  showmessage (MyMethod .ParamByName('ID').AsString);
  // AT THIS POINT, returned value is ONE.
  // I supposed that this Query had been filtered on 
  // the server and the client then show the filtered 
  // data, but it always shows the original query

  MyClientDs .Close;
end;
```

In the `DBGrid` The I see all records of Client Table, ALWAYS.

I try filter `ClientTable` clicking in the button, but in the `DBGrid` always appears all the record.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You didn't post any code, so answering your question is pretty much impossible. You need to edit your question to provide more information (including source code) in order for us to be able to try and help you.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
MyQuery.SQL.Clear;
MyQuery.SQL.Add(' SELECT * from CLIENT where ID = '+StrToInt (ID));
MyQuery.Open;
result := MyQuery.RecordCount; 
// ------------------------------------------------ 
// At this point, MyQuery.RecordCount = ONE record
// ------------------------------------------------
```

When you assign ID `StrToInt(ID)`, you are not creating a parameter. Therefore, later when you do the `ParamByName' to change it, there's no parameter there to change.

Change the lines above to

```
MyQuery.SQL.Text := `SELECT * FROM client WHERE ID  = :ID`;
MyQuery.ParamByName('ID').AsInteger := ID;
MyQuery.Open;
```

This should fix the problem.

Comment: I not use parameter in the query, i use parameter in the method MyMethod. Method, is like a funtion but through the server.

Comment: And this is ony a example. In ServerMethods if you define a var and change it from a funtion or procedure into de ServerMethods, when you leave the funtion or procedure, the var return to its initial value.

Comment: You're NOT using a parameter in the first query (the one with `StrToInt`), but you ARE here: `MyMethod .ParamByName('ID').Value := 5`. You need to use parameters in both places.

Comment: sure? I use parameters in MyMethod because it is how the methods used, but into de funtion, I generate a SQL sentence, not only change a parameter in the query, I change all the query. I send as a parameter the value 5, by example. And then, into the funtion, generate a sql sentence like "select * from client = 5". This is only a small example, really the sql sentence change much more, by this, I send to MyQuery.SQL a complete sql command and not only a parameter

Comment: That's not what your code shows. You were asked to post code; that means the **real** code you're having trouble  with, not something you made up that doesn't have the same problem. How do you expect to get help when you won't even try to work with us?

Comment: Thanks in advance. This is the same code, but very simplified. In fact, I'm trying to do has the same effect as using the property "CommandText". And if everything works perfectly CommandText use. I like send a complete source code, but not as attaching a file

Answer (score 0):

the answer to this in DSServerClass1.LifeCycle.

It was  "invocation". I've changed to "session".

There is a continuous disconnect to the server with "invocation"  and then restores the defaults.

Anyone knows how to work with "invocation"?